# SMTP getting error 554, Data command rejected: Access Manager - slot COS quota violation

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

I'm testing a java mail application to multiple sending, I'm sending something like 500 email to one mailbox from another just to see how long it takes to forward all emails. While I do that I get this:

```
INFO: DEBUG SMTP: got response code 554, with response: 554 5.7.1 <DATA>: Data command rejected: Access Manager - slot COS quota violation
```

I thought that the problem was something like the speed of sending emails is too much high, or that I was sending too much email to the same address.
If can help that emails are certified email sent by ssl to a smtps server.
Anyone have any idea of what exactly is going on?

Comment: Did you check that the recipient mailbox is not full ?

Comment: I didn't checked this but I don't think it is very important. How can it be involved in such a problem? We are talking about smtp...

Comment: OK. Full is probably the wrong word but 554 is usually something the SMTP server does not like either in the `from` or `to` header. Is your sender e-mail address limited/under quota on this server, the recipient e-mail address, the domain, etc...

Comment: From the error message it definitely sounds like you're exceeding some quota limit imposed by the SMTP server.  You might want to talk to your server administrator or vendor to get more details.

Comment: are u getting any such error while sending only 1 mail to recipient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COS usually refers to `Class of Service` which are actually a set of rules/policies created by admin for the mailboxes where one of possible rule is "Quota Violation".
These rules are created by Admin in order to check the fair usage policy of mailboxes.

The SMTP service check these rules for every mail that comes-in into the system.

In your case when you are sending 500 mails in one shot to single id its quite possible that the recipients mailbox is exceeding the allowed limit. In this case the SMTP server stops accepting any further mails for the recipient and starts giving a 5xx/4xx error to the sender

Comment: I contacted my smtp provider and I found out that there are a limit per minute on sending.